# Reshape Dataframe columns to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this;

```
Year   US  China   Russia
2007   NaN   45      12
2008   12    22       4
2009   12    NaN     41
```

I want it reshaped to look like this;

```
Year Country Value
2007  US      NaN
2007  China    45
2007  Russia   12
2008  US       12
2008  China    22
2008  Russia   4
2009  US       12
2009  China   NaN
2009  Russia    41
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just came across the `pd.melt()` function.

It works like this;

```
pd.melt(data,id_vars=['Year']).sort('Year')
```

Comment: Do `pd.melt(data,id_vars=['Year'],var_name='Country')` if you want your 2nd column to be called `Country` instead of `variable`. of course, you could always rename it later.